# Integer resource not what expected

Tags: android, android-resources

I have the following integer resources in my strings.xml file

```
<item type="integer" name="pID" format="integer">374</item>
<item type="integer" name="vID" format="integer">3468</item>
```

I want to call them from my code to get 374 and 3468.

However, when I output to Logcat...

```
Log.d("MainActivity.onCreate","pID: "+R.integer.pID+" vID: "+R.integer.vID);
```

I see the following...

```
pID: 2131230720 vID: 2131230721
```

Why are `R.integer.vID` and `R.integer.pID` returning ints other than 3468 and 374 respectivley?

Comment: You're printing out the resource IDs. You should use Resources.getInteger(resourceID) instead; http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer

Comment: Ooohhh gotcha. Thanks. Please post an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are printing out the resource IDs. Use `Resources.getInteger(resourceId)` instead.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer