# Integer resource not returning the correct value

Tags: java, android

In my `integer.xml` I have

```
<integer name="minUNameLen">6</integer>
```

And in my code I am :

```
if (uName.trim().length() < R.integer.minUNameLen) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        Splash.this.getApplicationContext(),
                        "Should be Min "+R.integer.minUNameLen+" characters long",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But instead of returning `6` I am getting `2131165….` a weird number in my code.
Can anybody tell what’s wrong in here?

---

Doing `Resources.getInteger(R.integer.minUNameLen)` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112180/integer-resource-not-what-expected) gives me `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getInteger(int) from the type Resources`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the resource ID you're seeing.

You need to use

```
getResources().getInteger(R.integer.minUNameLen)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `getResources().getInteger(R.integer.minUNameLen)` to get the value

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is the value of the variable `R.integer.minUNameLen`
What you need is: `Activity.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.minUNameLen)`

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Context` object instance to retrieve a `Resources` object instance and finally get the desired resource, an Integer in your case.

```
myActivity.getContext().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.yourIntegerID);
```

as `Activity` extends `Context` you can simply call

```
myActivity.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.yourIntegerID);
```